connecting flight by another Airlines within same Terminal in Dubai
I have to fly on Turkish airlines from San Francisco to Dubai via Istanbul and arrive in Terminal 1 in Dubai with two checked bags. Then I have to catch a self-connecting flight with Oman Airlines from the same Terminal 1 to Bangalore, India.
My flight from Istanbul to Dubai lands at 3:10 a.m.
Oman Airlines from Dubai to Bangalore leaves at 6:05 a.m. Even if my San Francisco flight is not delayed, I will have only around 2.5 hours to change planes.

What is the transfer procedure I have to do?
Will the time be enough for the transfer?
Will I have to go through security and customs again as a new passenger and check in my luggage?
Do I have to come out of the airport (from the Arrivals Hall in Terminal 1) to enter Departure Hall in Terminal 1?


Is this self-transfer or connecting (one PNR)? If the former, it looks pretty tight, personally I wouldn’t risk it. This Transfers guide should help

This is  a completely different PNR and self transfer.

So you're flying SF-Istanbul-Dubai-Muscat-Bangalore? Why on earth did you book this crazy connection when there are countless options to fly SFO-BLR with one stop or even direct?

@lambshaanxy Good question, also why on earth book a complicated flight itinerary without fully understanding the connection process and the risk level.

To add a final nail in the coffin of that plan, here is the recent flight history of TK758, your flight scheduled to arrive at 3:10 am in DXB (the scheduled arrival time is not the same every day):



Scheduled departure date
Scheduled arrival
Actual arrival




23 Oct
2:30
3:01


24 Oct
2:30
2:52


25 Oct
2:30
6:49


26 Oct
2:30
3:03


27 Oct
3:10
3:49


28 Oct
3:10
3:29


29 Oct
3:10
3:44


30 Oct
3:10
3:35


31 Oct
3:10
3:31


01 Nov
3:10
3:37


02 Nov
3:10
3:36


03 Nov
3:10
3:40



You'll notice that it didn't arrive on time on any of those dates, and even if we take away the delay of over 4 hours on 25/10, delays routinely exceed 20 minutes.
This is probably not TK's fault (I suppose it's due to the current situation in the region and the large detours that are required), but that doesn't change the fact that it makes the connection even more difficult if not impossible.

This depends a lot on whether this is a single ticket or two separate ticket (aka self connection).
Single Ticket: You have plenty of time. Your bags will be checked through and you don't need to go through immigration. You will go through security, but only with your carry on. Then you just follow the signs to your departure gate. If you miss the connection through no fault of your own, Oman airlines will rebook you on the next available flight for free
Separate Tickets: Very risky. You need to pass through immigration, collect your bags, pass through customs, and exit into the arrivals hall. You then need to make your way to the check-in counter and/or bag drop for Oman airlines and you need to be there before the cut off time (which is typically 1 hour before departure). Then you need to go through security and head to your departure gate where you need to be before the gate closing time. This seems to be 40 minutes before departure for Oman, but is often also printed on your boarding pass.
Note that will have to fully enter the United Arab Emirates, so you need the proper documentation to do so (Visa, passport, etc.), which depends on your citizenship.
If you miss the connection (for whatever reason) you will be considered a "no show" for your Oman Air flight and they will likely cancel your ticket. If you are lucky they may rebook you (for a fee) but it's also possible that you have to buy a brand new same-day ticket on the spot which can be quite expensive.

I believe, even though the plane will land in time , aircraft taxiing will take some time to get to the affiliated tarmac, then offloading of luggage, passing of immigration, security, luggage collection… It will take a lot of time. The most important thing is, as I will be considered as a New passenger ( My PNR  is different, as I have entered the Departure hall from  a city),I have to take into consideration closing of check in counters ( 1 hour before departure)and boarding gate . It seems, it will be very risky to take the flights change within 2.5 hours.

@ave The question is about the connection in DXB (arriving from IST), not IST. And since OP has separate tickets, they must go through immigration, reclaim bags, go to departures, check in, go through (main) security...

Guys, thanks a lot for Your valuable suggestions. We cancelled  all tickets and booked  a new one for Emirates airlines with layover in Dubai. we have lost some amount for cancellation ( small amount) .It was my first trip to USA and  now have learnt a lesson to NEVER EVER book multiple flights on a very long distance journey  , like from India to USA. Thanks again for Your advice and suggestions.
